# HTML FORM POST on Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have created a HTML form which works fine on my development and staging servers, however it is not working on the production environment.

Staging and production server URLs can be reached below:

Staging

Production

I am quite new to Rails and I will appreciate any kind of support. Below you can find the form code in the view template:

```
                  <%= form_for(@referral_form, url: submit_referral_form_url, method: :post, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
                <div class="contact-us-error"><ul></ul></div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Adınız & Soyadınız", required: true %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.text_field :phone, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Telefon Numaranız", required: true %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.text_field :friend_name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Arkadaşınızın Adı & Soyadı", required: true %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.text_field :friend_phone, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Arkadaşınızın Telefon Numarası", required: true %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.email_field :email, :class=>"form-control" ,  type:'email', required: true, placeholder: "Email Adresiniz" %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.text_area :message, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Arkadaşınızın Arabasının Özelliği (Yıl, Marka, Model vb)", required: true %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                  <%= f.hidden_field :campaign_name, :value => "Nusret-2017"%>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn createaccbtn" %>
                </div>
                <% end %>
```

Comment: What exactly about the form is not working in production?

Comment: Do you need to use a full URL? If so Have you viewed source of the post URL on production? It may be a configuration issue for that environment. If you can use a relative path then just change submit_referral_form_url to submit_referral_form_path

Comment: submit is not working.. I mean browser doesn't even issue POST to server..

Comment: As Tom mentioned, problem was related with the action URL.. Production environment runs on HTTPS, and staging on HTTP..  submit_referral_form_url created an HTTP URL and as Tom's suggestion when I changed it to path problem is solved!! @Tom can you please submit an answer so that I can close the question?

Comment: you using Ajax, make sure assets are compiling on production server.

Comment: @Tolga glad it worked. Just added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a relative path then just change `submit_referral_form_url` to `submit_referral_form_path`

Comment: Thanks for your support!